# What is the role of fully connected layer in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

What is the role of fully connected layer (FC) in deep learning? I've seen some networks have 1 FC and some have 2 FC and some have 3 FC. Can anyone explain to me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The fully connected layers are able to very effectively learn non-linear combinations of input features. Let's take a convolutional neural network for example.

The output from the convolutional layers represents high-level features in the data. While that output could be flattened and connected to the output layer, adding a fully-connected layer is a (usually) cheap way of learning non-linear combinations of these features.

Essentially the convolutional layers are providing a meaningful, low-dimensional, and somewhat invariant feature space, and the fully-connected layer is learning a (possibly non-linear) function in that space.

Comment: But what is it we are doing if we use 2 FC? for example AlexNet has FC (4096) and another FC (4096)

Comment: It's about abstraction. The more complex (abstract) features you can learn, the more robust model you have. So adding fully connected layer on the fully connected layer allows you just that. The previous FC layer learns some complex features, and the second one learns to combine knowledge from the previous one into some more complex knowledge. It's the basic idea behind the deep learning itself. The same thing happens with Conv layers and all the other layers, but it's easier to see that on conv layers analogy...

Comment: Is it right if i say the FC also allows to simplify dimensionality in a complex feature space? because in this layer we can specify the number of features. For example FC(100) means we retain/take 100 features out of thousands available feature produced from the previous layer? (sorry if i'm talking non sense)

Comment: No Because fc is not a filter, you cannot select features. Those 100 features are learned, like new features

Comment: So how do we determine the number of features? For example some people put different values in the FC such as FC (4096) in Alexnet. Why 4096? why not 1000?

Comment: The more the features, the more robust model is. But there is always a tradeoff between robustness and speed. The usual practice is to put the number of units as a power of number 2